# $\int_{-h}^{h}f(x)g(x)dx=f(C_h)\int_{-h}^{h}g(x)dx$

Tags: calculus

$f:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $g:[-1,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is nonnegative integrable. Show that there exist $0<C_h<h$ with $0<h<1$ such that
$$\int_{-h}^{h}f(x)g(x)dx=f(C_h)\int_{-h}^{h}g(x)dx$$

I think this question can be solved by mean value theorem for integral, but still don't know how to solve it. Could anyone give me some advice?

Comment: That is the [First mean value theorem for definite integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_definite_integrals).

Comment: thank you, this is indeed almost the same question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is correct.

Let $f(x)=x, g(x)=x^2$, then 
$$
\int_{-h}^h fg = 0, \int_{-h}^h g >0, 
$$
then if the equation holds, then $f(C_h)=0$, then $C_h = 0$, contradiction.

Comment: thank you. maybe I should modify the given condition to $0\leq C_h <h$?

Comment: I don't think you could prove this…… The 1st MVT of definite integral only guarantees $C_h \in [-1,1]$, so maybe you might find some other counterexamples.